# how to write react component to construct HTML DOM

Tags: angularjs, dom, reactjs

I'm started learning reactjs. I like to write react component that will read inputs from config file and generate a HTML DOM at run time.

config.json

```
{
  "select": {name: "cars", option: ["volvo", "audi"], style: "select2" }
}
```

The react component should return the following output

```
   <select name="cars" style="select2">
     <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
     <option value="audi">Audi</option>
   </select>
```

Any suggestions
Thanks in advance

Comment: please see my jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/prabud/sb4pq0mm/

Comment: Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
var config = require('./pathtoconfig');

var ComponentName = React.createClass({
    render() {

     var ops = config.select.option.map(function(o) {
        return <option value={o}>{o}</option>
     });

     var htmlEls = <div>
        <select name={config.select.name}>
            {ops}
        </select>
     </div>

     return (
        <div>{htmlEls}</div>
     );
    }
})
```

Comment: Nader, thanks for your reply, I unable to run this code in http://jsfiddle.net/prabud/sb4pq0mm/.

Comment: You can't require an entire file url, check out this one I've set up with the data locally for reference: https://jsfiddle.net/dabit3/swqo11up/1/

Answer (score 0):

Pasting here as the edit needs peer review to be visible...

```
var config = require('./pathtoconfig');

var ComponentName = React.createClass({
    render() {

     var ops = config.select.option.map(function(o) {
        return <option value={o}>{o}</option>
     });

     var htmlEls = <div>
        <select name={config.select.name} style={config.select.style}>
            {ops}
        </select>
     </div>

     return (
        {htmlEls}
     );
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the data you are repeating over, just like in angular. With that in mind, you should also be passing your state or props in to use in the component - this depends on whatever you have set up to run the models and controllers behind react. So with that in mind, you can do something like this :

See fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/kb3gN/13261/

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
render: function() {
     var ops = this.props.config.select.option.map(function(o) {
    return <option value={o}>{o}</option>
 })

 var htmlEls = <div>
    <select name="cars">
        {ops}
    </select>
 </div>
    return <div>{htmlEls}</div>;
}
});

var config = {
 "select": {name: "cars", option: ["volvo", "audi"], style: "select2" }
};

React.render(<Hello config={this.config} />, document.body);
```

Notice, I am passing the config var I just set onto the hello component, this is so I can use it on the current components props, like `this.props.config`. I recommend checking out some tutorials on how state and props are used and work within react components.

Just like in angulars `ng-repeat`, you have to know what level of the object you are using for the repeat you'd like to repeat over, so in your case it's  `this.props.config.select.option`.